# How do I detect if the app uses React Native, given APK file?

Tags: android, apk, react-native, decompiling

I downloaded APK file from Google Play, and want to know if the develop of the application have used React Native library. What's a quick and stable way to do that? (Would be even better if it's something I can potentially automate later - but such automation itself is out of scope of this question.)

Comment: why don't you just decompile the apk using dex2jar and look at the packages used inside the application.

Comment: What's the use case to know this detail?

Comment: @suman curiosity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can offer you 2 solutions:

- **Solution 1**

You can use [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases/download/2.0/dex-tools-2.0.zip).
When you open the generated jar file, you can check if it uses React Native if there is a folder `/com/facebook/react/`.

- **Solution 2**

  1. Rename your application APK `app.apk` into `app.zip`
  2. Decompress your zip file
  3. Use `dexdump` from Android`SDK`$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools//dexdump`:`dexdump classes.dex`
  4. Search for `com/facebook/react` in the output of dexdump

Comment: and if the packages names are obfuscated?

Comment: com.facebook.react won't be obfuscated (of proguarded correctly); otherwise it would not be able to be called/initialized.

Comment: is it possible to decompile react native JS back into JS?

Comment: @pstanton What do you mean react native JS back into JS? JavaScript is JavaScript...whether you are using React Naive or not.

Comment: @kojow7 I mean from an apk -> js source .. is that possible?

Comment: @pstanton No, you will never be able to get your original looking source files back. If you want further clarification it would be best to ask your own question.

Comment: @kojow7 there's nothing wrong with comments. feel free not to answer.

Comment: ✅ Tip: Android Studio can "Analyze APK", so you can do that option in the menu or just drag-and-drop the APK to it. Then click on the *.dex file

Comment: What if it has /com/facebook folder but no /react folder in it ?

Comment: @pstanton a _minified_ version of the JS code resides in `assets/index.android.bundle` (first, decompress the package as described in the answer)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted solution certainly will get you the right answer, but it will be quite slow. It is what I did originally, and it was not fast enough for my needs since I was running this script across hundreds of APKs. I developed an alternate solution and executed it before the original made it through 5% of the APKs.

The reason I don't like checking for layouts having com_facebook in the name (the other pre-existing solution) is that it is entirely plausible for an app to be using another Facebook SDK that contains a layout file starting with that string. I don't know of any false positives, but it seemed reasonably likely that there would be some.

Instead I check for the presence of `libreactnativejni.so` which I have to imagine only gets used if React Native is being used. (I originally was looking for libyoga.so, but I had a few false positives, I think because there's a logging library by the same name.)

Specifically, this condition on a Mac in a bash script is what I'm using (I think it's portable, but have not tested):

```
if [ "$(unzip -l $apkfile | grep libreactnativejni.so | wc -l)" -gt "0" ]
then 
echo "Uses RN"
fi
```

Comment: The only reason I don't want to change the accepted answer is because I don't have time to personally check it (as I did when I was asking original question and working on a project related to it).

Comment: What does `libreactnativejni.so` do? Some apps have those `/com/facebook/react/` things but do not have this SO file...

Comment: The shared object library is what powers a lot of the layout functionality for React Native Android (behind the scenes it actually uses `libyoga.so`, but other apps can include that as well without using RN). The com.facebook.react package has things beyond just RN stuff, though I haven't seen this case myself. Do you have an example app with that property?

Answer (score 6):

### The most simple solution

Open the ***APK*** in ***Android Studio*** and check the `classes.dex`-files(can be more the one file).
What you are looking for is:

- React Native - do you find folder `com\facebook\react` ?
- Flutter - do you find folder `io\flutter` ?
- Xamarin - do you find folder `com\xamarin\` ?

It could look like this in Android Studio

[image: Android Studio Apk files]

Answer (score 3):

> Not sure if this proven way.

Download the apk from the store to your PC, I used [APK Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/apkgk-downloader/) FireFox extension (if you don't have the app apk already).

Open apk with Zip software (I am on Linux so I used Ark).
Now you can see parts of the project.

Go to `res->layout` and search for `com_facebook...`, In my case it was `com_facebook_activity_layout.xml`.
If you have one layout with `com_facebook` in it then this apk was created with React.

Answer (score -1):

i found that the [Online APK Analyzer"](https://sisik.eu/apk-tool) built by [Roman Sisik](https://github.com/sixo) is helpful online tool to know the frameworks used to build an android app by just uploading the apk file.

I've tested it with flutter and react-native apps and it gave me the correct answer, i also noticed that when no framework is shown it probably means that the app was built natively.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.absinthe.libchecker
or if you want check on pc then use https://github.com/EngineerDanny/apk-framework-detector this one.