# How to know whether a *page* in an app is using React Native (or pure native)?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Note: I am *not* asking how to detect if an app uses React Native *somewhere inside* it (already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302269/how-do-i-detect-if-the-app-uses-react-native-given-apk-file)).

I wonder **which *pages (screens)* inside an app** is using RN and which pages are not, by examining the `apk` file or runtime checks etc. For instance, the Facebook app uses RN. However, it only uses RN for some seldom-used pages - that is completely a different story than using in every page.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

For who are interested in this: Maybe try to examine the *threads*, since JS engine is in a separate thread (if I remember correctly). If the page is rendered via React Native (JavaScript), the JS thread must need some CPU.

(P.S. I switch to Flutter in the end, so I no longer look at React native samples.)